# How can we add bounding box around canny edge detection output?

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

I am using canny edge detection and want to create an bounding box around the edges detected such that each word is covered under single bounding box.

Canny Edge Output -

[image]

Bounding box around canny edge output -

[image]

I have tried following approach

```
contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)


boundRect = [None]*len(contours)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    contours_poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
    boundRect[i] = cv2.boundingRect(contours_poly)

for i in range(len(contours)):
    cv2.rectangle(image, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3])), (0,0,0), 2)
```

but in this approach each alphabet individually gets bounding box.

Actual Ouptut -

[image]

Contouring output -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the function << [cv2.findContours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html) >>

It is used as this:

```
contours = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL) 
// contours : Numpy array with shape [number_contours, number_points,1,2]
// image: Your binary image as input
// cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL: Way to get your contours hierarchie
// cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE: Approximation for optimisation
```

[Contour hierarchie documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html)

[Approximation documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#contour-approximation-method)

I recommand you to not use a canny to solve your problem but a [threshold method](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html?highlight=threshold) insteed.

For letters detection, you can use an [ICP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) in order to be able to read the text automatically.

To trace your contours, use this code:

```
import random
contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)
for i in range(len(contours)):
    contour = contours[i]
    random.seed(i)
    color = (255*random.random(),255*random.random(),255*random.random())
    cv2.drawContours(img,[contour], -1, color, 3)
```

If there is too many contours for 1 element in your image you have to use the dilate method in order to "close" your contours:

```
img_dilate = cv2.dilate(image, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 1), (1, 1)))
```

[Contour approximation method documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)

Comment: I have updated the question you can check the output I am getting from your solution. Purpose isn't to find just the text but to find all different elements.

Comment: What's approx in `cv2.drawContours(img,[approx], -1, color, 3)`

Comment: I have shared the output for the same

Answer (score 1):

You might need to find contours and then apply bounding boxes. The following links can help :

1. **To find contours** :
   [Try this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#contours-getting-started)
2. **To draw bounding boxes** : 
   [Try this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html?highlight=bounding%20boxes#a-straight-bounding-rectangle)

Comment: Yes I have tried that but in that case each alphabet gets an bounding box.

Comment: for the function cv2.findContours, pass the flag cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, instead of cv2.RETR_LIST

Comment: Still each alphabet have different box.

Comment: we can do dilate first and then try finding contours